# How to generate all order-relations consistent with an additive value-function?

Tags: combinatorics

There is a finite set $X$. Each item $x\in X$ has a positive value, $v(x)$. Each value function $v$ induces an order-relation $\prec$ on the subsets of $X$:

$$ Y\prec Z \iff \sum_{y\in Y}v(y) < \sum_{z\in Z} v(z)$$

An order-relation on subsets of $X$ is called *additive* if there exists a positive value-function $v$ that induces it. For example, suppose $X := \{x,y\}$. Then the following order-relation is additive:

$$ \emptyset \prec \{x\} \prec \{y\} \prec \{x,y\} $$

bu the following order-relation is not:

$$ \emptyset \prec \{x\}\prec \{x,y\}  \prec \{y\} $$

MY QUESTION IS: given a set of items, what is a way to generate all the additive preference-relations over its subsets?

Comment: The number is multiplication of two functions: $n!\cdot f(n)$. $f(n)$ is total number of arrangements under assumption that $x_1<x_2<...<x_n$ and I don't know what it is yet.

Comment: It appears that formula is $n!\cdot (2n-4)!!$.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following works . . .

First, some notation . . .

Let $X_0 = {\large{\varnothing}}$.

For each positive integer $n$,

- Let $X_n = \{1,...,n\}$.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $P_n$ denote the power set of $X_n$.$\\[4pt]$

  Let $Q_n = \{S \in P_n \mid n \in S\}$.

The goal is to find all additive orders on $X_n$ (i.e., a preference ordering of $P_n$).

We'll say an additive order on $X_n$ has "ascending singletons" if
$$1 < 2 < \cdots  < n$$
or more precisely, $i < j \implies \{j\}$ is preferred to $\{i\}$.

For simplicity (and without loss of generality), we only consider additive orders with ascending singletons (so in what follows, the term "additive order" *means* additive order with ascending singletons).

Determine the additive orders recursively.

To determine a unique additive order on $X_n$, first choose an additive order on $X_{n-1}$, retaining only the subset comparisons, not any particular positive valuation which might have induced the order.

The chosen additive order on $X_{n-1}$ forces a unique preference order on $Q_n$.

Thus, at this point, the preference order is already determined for pairs $(A,B)$ with

- $A,B \in P_{n-1}$.$\\[4pt]$

  $A,B \in Q_n$.$\\[4pt]$

  $A \in P_{n-1}$, $B \in Q_n$, and $A \subset B$.$\\[4pt]$

We need the concept of "domination" (forced preference) . . .

It's recursive.

Given subsets $A,B$ of $X_n$, we say $B$ dominates $A$ if

- $B$ is already known to be preferred to $A$.

  or, assuming there's not yet any known preference for $A$ vs $B$:

  if $A$ can be each be partitioned as $A = A_1 \cup A_2$, and $B$ can be partitioned as $B = B_1 \cup B_2$ where $B_1$ dominates $A_1$ and $B_2$ dominates $A_2$.

If $B$ dominates $A$, then we force $B$ to be preferred to $A$ (if that was not already the case).

Stated without proof, here's what I think is true . . .

Merge the orders of $P_{n-1}$ and $Q_n$, retaining the internal orders of $P_{n-1}$ and $Q_n$, while making sure that in the merge, preferences forced by the the principle of domination are respected. Moreover, as each element of $B$ is inserted, the domination relation may need to be updated.

Claim: Any choice of such a merge yields a unique additive order on $X_n$, and every additive order on $X_n$ which is consistent with the chosen additive order on $X_{n-1}$ can be obtained by this process.

Comment: I am not sure the claim is true... Let $n=3$. Suppose the order on $P_2$ is $\emptyset < 1 < 2 < 1,2$. So the order on $Q_3$ is $3 < 3,1< 3,2< 3,1,2$. Then, one of the merged orders according to your rule is $\emptyset < 1  < 3 < 3,1 < 2 < 3,2 < 1,2 < 3,1,2$. But this is not consistent with an additive function, since $1<3$ while $3,2<1,2$.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem. Maybe there's a fix.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the fix is easy -- just require ascending singletons.

Comment: What do you mean by ascending singletons?

Comment: I defined it as assuming
$$1 < 2 < \cdots < n$$

Comment: With ascending singletons, there is only one order on $P_2$, namely $\emptyset < 1 < 2 < 1,2$.  The corresponding order on $Q_3$ is $3 < 1,3 < 2,3 < 1,2,3$. One way to  combine these orders while maintaining the ascending singletons property is $\emptyset < 1 < 2 < 3 < 1,3 < 1,2 < 2,3 < 1,2,3$. But, this is not additive since $2<3$ while $1,3<1,2$...

Comment: Ok. it's not as simple as I thought. I think the merge has not allow insertion at a point that would be dominated. Other than that, I think it's free choice. It's still just a conjecture, but I'll edit that in (until you break that!).

Comment: I might have to fully delete this and go back to square 1, but I'll hold off to see if my latest attempt holds up (I'm not all that optimistic).